# Why does the WiFi symbol have "R" text on it?

Tags: wi-fi

I have this strange "R" on my WiFi signal.

[image: Image of Wifi icon]

It's not on my cell signal and it's not a glitch. It seems to be set when I am on WiFi, but I don't know why. Sometimes it's there, sometimes it goes away.

The only way I am able to fix the issue is by restarting the phone, but **does anyone know why this happens?**

When I look online, everyone seems to not know what the main problem is and most threads give up and stop trying to figure out what is going on.

Comment: do you have some VPN app installed?

Comment: @Esther that is a good question. I have no VPN apps installed. I used to have OpenVPN app back on my old phone but I just got a new phone a month ago and I just checked my apps to double check; and there is no VPN apps currently installed.

Comment: What is your phone model, manufacturer and which Android version is running?

Comment: Have you tried turning off roaming in your settings? The R stands for roaming.

Comment: @Mastaxx This is the WiFi icon, roaming does not apply there.

Comment: I know, but from what i read from other users having this problem it appears roaming still needs to be turned off to get rid of it?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense. Roaming refers to your device not being in its home country and using the network where it is, in most places (outside of the EU) at increased cost. For this to apply, it would have to for example geolocate the external IP it uses and then decide to show said icon, which has no added value. WiFi is WiFi, and almost always freely available...

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a built in VPN function on the asker's phone that either kicks in or is buggy. Can you please answer @Robert's question on which model, manufacturer and Android version you have?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Robert and MiG. The model: Moto G Stylus (2021). Manufacturer: Motorola. Android Version: 10 (build number QPCS30.Q4-31-26-1-9)

Comment: Thanks! And which WiFi network is it connected to when said 'R' is displayed? Is it a specific one or ones at certain locations, or does this also happen to for example your home network?

Comment: Only my home network. Its usually connected to the wifi extender's ssid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For as far as I can tell so far it seems to be a bug, specifically with Motorola Android devices (Motorola themselves do not list WiFi-with-R in their [glossary of terms](http://www.motorola.com/hc/3083/41/verizon/en-us/d0e15.html) and [WiFi troubleshooting section](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/148853/) either).

I've seen one [mention](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/1008406-why-new-r-wifi-not-cell-signal.html) that a **factory reset** might resolve this, so if it's particularly annoying it's worth a try.

If you want to help squash said bug I would first [contact them](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/mcp/contactus) before performing that reset though, maybe they can finally track it down and fix it for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your WiFi has a repeater (like a range extender). Or your AP was in repeater mode.

Comment: For those not familiar, AP = Access Point.